# Unable to `pip install` locust on M1 MacBook Pro on Monterey 12.3

Tags: macos, locust

- 2021 MacBook Pro, Apple M1 Max Chip, Monterey 12.3
- python: 3.8.9
- pip: 22.2.2
- locust: 2.12.1

it looks like there's an error installing one of the dependencies - `gevent`

```
Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
```

Comment: Need more details (complete output). Also, looks like a problem with gevent rather than locust itself?

Comment: It seems that yours is relate to mine, please refer if any help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083975/error-failed-building-wheel-for-gevent-when-installing-locust.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using other `gevent` versions, you can [get them here](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/).
It works well with the below packages on my MacBook Pro.

```
[packages]
gevent = "==22.8.0"
locust = "==2.12.2"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```