# ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent when installing Locust

Tags: python, locust

**ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects when install Locust**

```
tu@Yans-MacBook-Pro locust-py % pipenv install locust
Installing locust...
Error:  An error occurred while installing locust!
Error text: Collecting locust
  Using cached locust-2.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (823 kB)
Collecting roundrobin>=0.0.2
  Using cached roundrobin-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting gevent>=20.12.1
  Using cached gevent-22.10.1.tar.gz (6.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting flask>=2.0.0
  Using cached Flask-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Collecting msgpack>=0.6.2
  Using cached msgpack-1.0.4-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (74 kB)
Collecting pyzmq!=23.0.0,>=22.2.1
  Using cached pyzmq-24.0.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_15_universal2.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=2.0.0
  Using cached Werkzeug-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (232 kB)
Collecting geventhttpclient>=2.0.2
  Using cached geventhttpclient-2.0.8-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (42 kB)
Collecting Flask-Cors>=3.0.10
  Using cached Flask_Cors-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.23.0
  Using cached requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting ConfigArgParse>=1.0
  Using cached ConfigArgParse-1.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting Flask-BasicAuth>=0.2.0
  Using cached Flask_BasicAuth-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psutil>=5.6.7
  Using cached psutil-5.9.2-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (239 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
  Using cached Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting click>=8.0
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
  Using cached itsdangerous-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting Six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting zope.interface
  Using cached zope.interface-5.5.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl (210 kB)
Collecting greenlet<2.0,>=1.1.3
  Using cached greenlet-1.1.3.post0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl (93 kB)
Collecting zope.event
  Using cached zope.event-4.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/tu/.local/share/virtualenvs/locust-py--yU_S3D0/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from gevent>=20.12.1->locust->-r /var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pipenv-_sjpy_em-requirements/pipenv-k3yuverh-requirement.txt (line 1)) (65.3.0)
Collecting brotli
  Using cached Brotli-1.0.9-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (421 kB)
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl (161 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.1.1
  Using cached MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: gevent
  Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build gevent

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for gevent (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [351 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent
      copying src/gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent
      copying src/gevent/_greenlet_primitives.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent
      copying src/gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent
      copying src/gevent/backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent
      copying src/gevent/time.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue639.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__hub_join_timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_multiple_imports.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__joinall.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_logging.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__nondefaultloop.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__core_loop_run.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__example_wsgiserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__greenletset.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__backdoor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__GreenletExit.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__refcount.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__refcount_core.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__doctests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test___config.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__resolver_dnspython.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/_import_wait.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__destroy_default_loop.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__core_timer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__issues461_471.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue6.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__events.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__greenio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__environ.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__getaddrinfo_import.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__example_webproxy.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__threading_native_before_monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__local.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__api_timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue467.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__threading_holding_lock_while_monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_selectors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_close.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__order.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test___monitor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue600.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__memleak.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__execmodules.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__contextvars.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__example_portforwarder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__systemerror.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__exc_info.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_ex.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__lock.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__server.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__issue1864.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_timeout.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__pywsgi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__semaphore.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__core_fork.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_ssl_warning3.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__loop_callback.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/getaddrinfo_module.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__threadpool_executor_patched.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__subprocess_interrupted.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__real_greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__selectors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__ares_host_result.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_ssl_warning2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__example_echoserver.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/_import_import_patch.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__socket_ssl.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_ssl_warning.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__threading_2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__event.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__signal.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/_import_patch.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__monkey_queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test__thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/_ffi
      copying src/gevent/_ffi/callback.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/_ffi
      copying src/gevent/_ffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/_ffi
      copying src/gevent/_ffi/loop.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/_ffi
      copying src/gevent/_ffi/watcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/_ffi
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/skipping.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/patched_tests_setup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/exception.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/params.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/leakcheck.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/travis.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/support.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/testcase.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/monkey_test.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/switching.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/hub.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/timing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/six.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/sysinfo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/resources.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/sockets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/modules.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/openfiles.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/errorhandler.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/testrunner.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      copying src/gevent/testing/flaky.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/libev
      copying src/gevent/libev/_corecffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/libev
      copying src/gevent/libev/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/libev
      copying src/gevent/libev/corecffi.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/libev
      copying src/gevent/libev/watcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/libev
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/thread.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/dnspython.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/_addresses.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/ares.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/blocking.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      copying src/gevent/resolver/_hostsfile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/resolver
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/threadpool_no_monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/issue1526_with_monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/issue1526_no_monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/threadpool_monkey_patches.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/issue302monkey.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/script.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/monkey_package/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests/monkey_package
      copying src/gevent/tests/sha256.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/nullcert.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/https_svn_python_org_root.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/wrongcert.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/keycert.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/2_7_keycert.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/badkey.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/badcert.pem -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/server.crt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test_server.crt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/tests_that_dont_monkeypatch.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/tests_that_dont_do_leakchecks.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/hosts_file.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/tests_that_dont_use_resolver.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/test_server.key -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      copying src/gevent/tests/server.key -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/tests
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing/coveragesite
      copying src/gevent/testing/coveragesite/sitecustomize.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent/testing/coveragesite
      warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
      
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310/gevent.libuv._corecffi.c'
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-310
      Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' in /private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34
      configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/deps/libev':
      configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
      See `config.log' for more details
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 412, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 397, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 494, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 360, in run_setup
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/normal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 143, in run
          ext.sources[0] = make_mod(self.build_temp, pre_run)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-4ay0um8z/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 128, in make_mod
          pre_run(ext, ffi)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/_setuputils.py", line 381, in pre_run
          action()
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/_setuplibev.py", line 55, in configure_libev
          system(libev_configure_command)
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/_setuputils.py", line 195, in system
          if _system(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs):
        File "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/_setuputils.py", line 191, in _system
          return check_call(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 369, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/private/var/folders/n3/f_f4s9_16v11k9n402fn_lyc0000gn/T/pip-install-ean31kds/gevent_31ac438a728f499f901036ad42433a34/deps/libev"  && sh ./configure -C > configure-output.txt )' returned non-zero exit status 77.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**Notes**

- It has the same issue when using "pip3 install -U locust" or trying installing on the other Macbook Air

**Environment**

- OS: macOS Monterey Version 12.6
- Python version: Python 3.10.8, pip 22.3, pipenv: version 2022.10.12
- Locust version: locust 2.12.1, locust 2.12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue, the gevent 22.10.1 is just released yesterday (Released: Oct 15, 2022) causes the problem. I installed the following versions and it works well.

```
[packages]
gevent = "==22.8.0"
locust = "==2.12.2"

[requires]
python_version = "3.10"
```

Comment: Great that you got it working! I added some instructions to the Locust wiki documentation that might be more generally appropriate: https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/Installation#error-failed-building-wheel-for-xxx

Comment: Thanks @Cyberwiz for adding it to the docs